# Simple ToDo-List doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

My ToDo List dont wanna work the way i want. I've just been working with JavaScript for 2 weeks sthis is very new to me, therefor the code maybe doesnt look that nice.

The result comes out wrong. If I type in "buy food" the first line gonna show just that, but the next time I wanna add "walk the dog", then it displays

- buy food
- buy food
- walk the dog

I hope you understand my problem. It also ends the unordered list tag after the first click and adds the rest of the things in another.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var taskList = [];

var text = "<ul>"

function addToList() {
    var task = document.getElementById("toDoTask").value;
    taskList.push(task);

    for(i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++){
        text += "<li>" + taskList[i] + "</li>" ;
    }

    text += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById("todoList").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you're closing the ul tag after adding each item. Instead of concatenating raw HTML, consider using element objects and appending, and using a text node object to handle the user input - this removes the possibility of a DOM Based XSS vulnerability.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var taskList = [];

  var container = document.getElementById("todoList");
  
  document.getElementById("add").onclick = addToList;

  function addToList() {
    var task = document.getElementById("toDoTask").value;
    taskList.push(task);
 
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li;

    for (i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskList[i]))
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(ul);
  }

};
```

```html
Task:
<input id="toDoTask" /> <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />

<div id="todoList">

</div>
```

Comment: Why can't I write `onclick = addToList()` in the html code? I'm doing exactly the way you showed except that I wrote `<input type="button"  value="Add" onClick="addToList()" /> ` and therefor also deleted ` document.getElementById("add").onclick = addToList;` I don't know which way is the best, I'm just taught the other way to begin with.

Comment: In my example you can't simply change it like that because addToList function is not in the global scope (it is in a new protected scope). Doing it in the HTML is called inline and obstrusive, considered bad practice. Doing it in the JavaScript itself is good practice and unobstrusive.

Comment: Okay! Changed it to the good practice now. But one more question, if thats okay... in every `<li>`I want to write out the task and "[done]". Which gonna be a link and if you click it, the task will end up in the bottom on the list and have a line-through. I tried this `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskList[i] + "<a id='done'>[done]</a>"))` but as you might understand, it writes out the whole line and not [done] as a link. How do I fix this? And if you have a good tip on how to do the completeTask function I would be grateful.

Comment: createTextNode can only take actual text, not HTML, if you pass any HTML, it will be treated as plain text (this is why it protects you from XSS). Try `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('[done]')); li.appendChild(a)`. This will add the done link to each item. You can add a click event to it like `a.onclick = function(){ }` to handle the actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

On each call of function `addToList()` you should reset the variable `text`.

For example:

```
function addToList() {
  var task = document.getElementById("toDoTask").value;
  taskList.push(task);

  text="";

  for(i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++){
      text += "<li>" + taskList[i] + "</li>" ;
  }

  text += "</ul>";

  document.getElementById("todoList").innerHTML = text;
}
```

The whole list of items in array will appends to variable `text` on each call.

Comment: This worked out fine, and I understand that I rest the text variable. Just not hundred why this is necessary. Do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: You have declared the variable `text` outside of your function `addToList()`. So this variable is globally accessable in your namespace. In your function you append the items in your array via `+=` operator to the `text` variable. Alternatively you could declare the `text` variable inside the function `addToList()` with the same effect. The solution from @MrCode is more elegant and safer. So one upvote to him ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the innerHtml. This replace all the text of your content. You should just add the li to your ul.
You can do that by using the append function by [jquery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

your `<ul>` must contain an id like this `<ul id="toDoList">`

then you make `$("#toDoList").append("yourTask")`;

yourTask must contains the li.

With this, you don't need to iterate on all your element list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you seem to keep adding to `text` the second time, so text will be something like `<ul><li>buy food</li></ul><li>buy food</li><li>walk the dog</li></ul>`, which is invalid HTML by the way, but gets outputted anyway...